# IDAPython: Get the operand string without any substitutions

Tags: ida, idapython

I would like to get the operands of assembly instructions; represented as strings, without any local-variable substitution (e.g. instead of [rbp+var_200] I want to get the actual [rbp+XXXX] offset string). Is there an easy way to achieve this from IDAPython?

Cheers,
Thomas

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you really want the string, or do you want the offset?

Comment: I want the [rbp+xxxx] string, the offset alone will not do (as it would imply I have to do my own SIB parsing?)